# RTSP Stream not receiving data (C# and Sockets)

Tags: c#, sockets, rtsp

```
---------------REQUEST-------------------
DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.201:554 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
User-Agent: Dummy
Accept: application/sdp

----------------------------------


-----------------RESPONSE-----------------
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Date: Wed, Mar 22 2000 05:32:28 GMT
Server: RTSP Server (v1.2.3)
Content-Base: rtsp://192.168.1.201:554/
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 440

v=0
o=H.264 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.1.201
s=RTSP Server (v1.2.3)
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
i=SP5562HSM
t=0 0
a=range:npt=now-
a=control:*
a=etag:1234567890
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:1500
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=control:trackID=0
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001E;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IA
HukCg/I=,aM44gA==
a=x-dimensions:320,240
a=sendonly
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=control:trackID=1
a=sendonly

----------------------------------
---------------REQUEST-------------------
SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.201:554/trackID=0 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=58830-58831
User-Agent: Dummy

----------------------------------


-------------RESPONSE---------------------
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Date: Wed, Mar 22 2000 05:32:29 GMT
Server: RTSP Server (v1.2.3)
Session: 2154251319;timeout=80
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=58830-58831;server_port=6004-6005



----------------------------------
SESSION:  2154251319;
SERVER PORT (inp): 6004
---------------REQUEST-------------------
SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.201:554/trackID=1 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
Session: 2154251319;
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=58835-58836
User-Agent: Dummy

----------------------------------


----------------RESPONSE------------------
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Date: Wed, Mar 22 2000 05:32:32 GMT
Server: RTSP Server (v1.2.3)
Session: 2154251318;timeout=80
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=58835-58836;server_port=6002-6003



----------------------------------
---------------REQUEST-------------------
PLAY rtsp://192.168.1.201:554/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
----------------------------------


----------------RESPONMSE------------------
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Date: Wed, Mar 22 2000 05:32:33 GMT
Server: RTSP Server (v1.2.3)
Session: 2154251318;timeout=80
Range: npt=now-


----------------------------------
```

This is a log of my requests and responses. I have a separate thread listening on port 58830 accepting udp packets (Tested sending udp from another computer and were received).

Wireshark shows the requests and response but no udp packets. I looked at the back and forth between server and vlc and my request are almost identical but I still receive no udp video data

Comment: First check on wireshark/ethereal. It will good if you can send wireshark log of RTSP

Comment: tried that and i dont see any udp com

Answer (score 0):

Your SDP File's `IN` ADDR seems invalid 0.0.0.0...

Some stacks use the information in the SDP and this could explain why you are not receiving any packets on the address your are listening on.

Also it looks like you are doing multicast, have you ensured you setup the socket correctly before hand?